# Why can I not open my Python app after converting to .exe?

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a Python app with a Tkinter GUI. It runs fine as a Python program. Then I use PyInstaller to convert it to a .exe:

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w 'AttnyDistApp.py'
```

This completes fine, but when I try to open my app, I get the following error message:

[image]

But the GUI does not connect to a database - it's only after the user has clicked a button.

Comment: The error message seems clear and it appears most likely that you're wrong and the code does actually try to create a database connection before the error appears. We can't tell because you didn't share any code.

Comment: Okay, I figured out that it's because I'm running the following before I create the GUI:

from pyzipcode import ZipCodeDatabase
zcdb = ZipCodeDatabase()

But I still don't know why this isn't working correctly when I convert it to an .exe

Answer (score 1):

Your problem occurs likely because `ZipCodeDatabase` tries to load a database that is not included by PyInstaller. You'll need to find out what file it is trying to open and modify the configuration of PyInstaller to include that non-code file. PyInstaller is pretty good at finding all the code it needs to include, but data and binaries are often missed.

From the `pyzipcode` [documentation](https://pypi.org/project/pyzipcode/): "This package will allow you to get zip code information. The data used in this package can be retrieved from " - you should either include the file you downloaded yourself, or have your code check if the data is available and if it isn't, download it from the code before opening the database.